# Error syncing .less files when I push to Heroku app using asset_sync gem?

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, less, assets

I have a Rails 3.2.12 app and I was trying to sync my assets using an Amazon S3 bucket and the asset_sync gem for my Heroku app.
I've looked on the whole github issues tracker and here on SO, but wasn't able to find an answer to this. So here's my question:

Is it possible to sync .less files using the asset_sync gem?

After I push to Heroku, I get in the logs this error:

> ```
> Running: rake assets:precompile
>    rake aborted!
>    variable @inputHeight is undefined
>    (in /tmp/build_tejom7tf9zq9/app/assets/stylesheets/utils-and-mixins.less)
> ```

In order to config my app I followed the wiki from the [asset_sync github page](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) and to set my ENV variables I used the Built-in Initializer.

Here are the modifications in my production.rb file in order to fit the asset_sync requirements:

```
  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  config.assets.precompile += [ '*.css' ]

  # Serving Assets From S3 on Heroku
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "//s3.amazonaws.com/test"

  # store assets in a 'folder' instead of bucket root
  config.assets.prefix = "/production/assets"

end
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Edit 1:

I tried even running separately in my command line:

```
heroku run rake assets:precompile --app <yourapp>
```

but it didn't help, it threw the same error.

Edit 2:

I guess this is what you asked for:

```
....
gem 'less-rails', '~> 2.3.2'

gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '2.2.6'


# Gems used only for assets and not required in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.11.4', platforms: :ruby
  gem 'asset_sync'
end
```

Comment: Can you give the gem file?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to make it work by writing in my production.rb the specific .css file names that I wanted to include to my S3 bucket:

```
 # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "//s3.amazonaws.com/test"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  config.assets.precompile += %w( public.css users.css admin.css )
```